# Materialized view in Oracle Sql

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, mobile-safari

How can I use materialized view in order to increase the performance? I know oracle views get stored in the cache memory except the first time when client querying the view. We use materialized view to get the snapshot of the database usually when the size of data is very large,but I want to know where this materialized view gets stored ?Can it be stored in the client machine remotely(in indexedDB) to improve the performance ?

Comment: Have you done any prior research regarding this?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question I have edited it.I want to know is there any way I can store the details of my materialized view on web browser's local storage or on the client's machine in order to increase the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Views are just *stored queries*, they don't contain any data & don't occupy space on disk. If they are complex and deal with a lot of data, yes - fetching data will be slow (just as if you ran that `SELECT` itself).

Materialized views (MV) do contain data and occupy space on disk (which one? Server's, of course, where the database is). They "act" as if they were tables - if you use the same query you used for an *ordinary* view and create a *materialized* view, you could index the MV which could (and probably would) help accessing data faster.

On the other hand, views always *contain* the most recent data. Materialized views have to be refreshed. There are different ways to do that; one option is to refresh *on commit*, i.e. whenever data is committed in a table that is a base for the MV. Or, you could do that in a scheduled manner (for example, every night at 02:00) - that depends on how often you need to have the most recent data.

Much more info in documentation, e.g. "Materialized view concepts" (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/repmview.htm#REPLN003).